# How to set @Url.Content for an image in AngularJs MVC Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I am trying to upload an image and display it in my application. I am working in AngularJS,  MVC and Web APi. My Image uploads successfully to a folder.

Issue is: After uploading I send back relative path as Http response and set it to my controller $scope property which in turn I want to bind with img src. I am not sure if this is proper way to do it or not. Please guide is this wrong or what I am doing wrong.

My view is:

```
 <div class="profilePic">
       <img src="@Url.Content(UserDetails.PrflPic)" alt="Sample Image" />
 </div>
 <input type="file" valid-file upload="uploadFile(file)" ng-model="file">
```

Here "UserDetails.PrflPic" is my $scope property that I want to use some how. But, I cannot do this because Url.Content takes string only. I tried this @Url.Content({{UserDetails.PrflPic}}) which also is not fine.

My Controller Method is:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function (file) {
        
        var PromiseData = UserService.uploadProfilePicture(file);
        PromiseData.then(function (Response) {
            alertify.alert('Image uploaded sucessfully');
            $scope.UserDetails.PrflPic = Response.data;
            $scope.$apply();
           
        }, function (Error) {$scope.$apply();
            alertify.alert('Some issue occurred while saving picture');
        });
    }
```

File Upload Api as:

```
 public IHttpActionResult Post()
        {
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

            // Check if files are available
            if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[0];

                var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/UserProfilePic/");
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }

                // Fetch the File Name.
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);

                // Save the File.
                postedFile.SaveAs(path + fileName);

                var ImgLoc = "~/UserProfilePic/" + fileName;
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, ImgLoc);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("No files to upload.");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 <img ng-src="{{UserDetails.PrflPic}}" alt="Sample Image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-src` directive allows you to bind the src attribute.

```
<img ng-src="{{UserDetails.PrflPic}}" alt="Sample Image" />
```